# DNS caching not clearing Mac OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, dns

Something weird is happening on my machine. I'm waiting on a domain to propagate. I visit the page in chrome and it's not there yet. but if i look at it on another machine, on another ISP, it's there.

I've tried flushing the cache with `dscacheutil -flushcache` and `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` and still not there.

If I use `dig`, I get this, which has the incorrect dns entries:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> http://www.xxx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 37789
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;http://www.xxx.com.    IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xxx.com.    3174    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com. hostmaster.registrar-servers.com. 2014090300 3600 1801 604800 3601

;; Query time: 31 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.1#53(10.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Oct 17 09:26:21 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119
```

if I use `dig +trace`, the last two steps show the correct dns entries:

```
;; Received 448 bytes from 000.0.00.00#53(000.0.00.00) in 79 ms

xxx.com.    86400   IN  NS  ns1.correctns.com.
000.0.00.00.    86400   IN  NS  ns2.correctns.com.
;; Received 96 bytes from 1000.0.00.00#53(1000.0.00.00) in 78 ms

000.0.00.00.    86400   IN  SOA ns1.correctns.com. ns2.correctns.com. 2014101603 86400 7200 3600000 86400
;; Received 138 bytes from 66.117.5.83#53(66.117.5.83) in 68 ms
```

I honestly don't know what I'm looking at here, but it seems like it's caching the wrong info and then always referring to that instead of the fresh info from the `+trace` run?

I have this happen very frequently. Is there any way I can force it to look in the right place?

Comment: I've heard a few reports of that recently, but no definitive fixes. Does a reboot help at all?

Comment: @Tetsujin nope. I've left it overnight and it's still showing the caching. would really love to get to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's being cached by the DNS server at 10.0.0.1 (probably your router). There are two potential levels of caching involved, and flushing one of them doesn't affect the other. Let me run through the options:

- `dig +trace domainname.com` traces the DNS query through authoritative servers, in your case getting the final answer from 66.117.5.83.
- `dig domainname.com` just sends the query to the DNS server configured in your network settings (in your case 10.0.0.1). This is usually just a caching server, which will remember results it's looked up before, and hand out the same answer until its time-to-live expires (in `xxx.com.    3174    IN  SOA dns1.registrar-servers.com...`, it has 3174 seconds to go).
- Using the domain with normal (non-DNS-oriented) programs like Chrome go through OS X's resolver, which checks its cache (same TTL policy applies here), and if it's not there checks the configured DNS server (remember that that's probably a caching server).

Resetting the OS X cache doesn't affect the cache at the DNS server. Also, note that even if you reset your DNS server (e.g. by rebooting your router), other DNS servers throughout the net may still have the old info cached. In general, when you make a DNS change, you have to wait for the TTL to expire before assuming the new info is available everywhere.

(And actually, there's another level you have to worry about -- your secondary DNS servers only check the primary server for updates periodically, so you have to wait for the secondary to update, THEN for the TTL to expire all the old info out of various caches...)

Answer (score 0):

All working fine far as I can tell.  The domain xxx.com seems to be synchronized and working just fine.  Also noticed you used `dig http://www.xxx.com`.  Dig dosen't understand URLs, try with just the domain name part,  `dig www.xxx.com`, so you get a correct response.

```
$ dig www.xxx.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3-Ubuntu <<>> www.xxx.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45553
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.xxx.com.                   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.xxx.com.            86331   IN      A       141.0.173.173

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 
;; WHEN: Sun Oct 19 16:44:50 MDT 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Here's the nameserver details.

```
$ checksoa xxx.com

     Serial #   RTT(ms)  Version                       Nameservers (name, IP, SOA mname field) for xxx.com

    2014040205      80   not currently available       ns4.serverstack.com       69.55.56.130                       SOA: ns1.serverstack.com
    2014040205     111   not currently available       ns1.serverstack.com       69.55.62.180                       SOA: ns1.serverstack.com
    2014040205     185   not currently available       ns2.serverstack.com       141.0.173.228                      SOA: ns1.serverstack.com
    2014040205     174   not currently available       ns3.serverstack.com       87.233.226.25                      SOA: ns1.serverstack.com
```

You may have to clear your local DNS caches if this is not being refreshed.  The negative cache TTL is what gets you on newly added records.  In this case, the negative TTL is 1800 seconds for xxx.com, so you could just wait that 30 minutes and it'll clear up on it's own.

This is a common problem.  You make a DNS change to add a new record and then you lookup the name immediately, before it's had a few minutes to propagate to all name servers, so you get a negative cache entry right before it was live and thus have to wait the full time (30 minutes), or resort to flushing local DNS caches to get it working.

PS:  For those that will berate me for believing xxx.com was the real domain, don't bother.  I know it's bogus, but my point is to leave in the real domains otherwise the help is limited.  I hate guessing as much as the next guy.  Use the real domains people.